# Merge [nw.js] and [node-webkit]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I suggested a tag synonym of [nw.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nw.js) for the existing tag [node-webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-webkit).  Node-webkit has recently been renamed to nw.js, and Stack Overflow users are now using both tags.  They should be merged.

Also, in keeping up with the Jones', GitHub has also renamed its competitor to nw.js from [atom-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom-shell) to [electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/electron).  I don't have enough rep to suggest a tag synonym there, but we should probably tackle this change at the same time.

Since the new names are nw.js and electron respectively, these tags should probably be the ones that people see?  Anyone have any thoughts on that?

Comment: Oh, I get it, "atom-shell"... "electron". That's cute.

Comment: If "nw.js" is the new one, wouldn't it be better to make "node-webkit" a synonym of it?  Tag admin is one area I've not done anything much with, so I could be wrong...!

Comment: @JamesThorpe I think you're right.  The nw.js should be the parent tag.